# Is it possible to use client certificates in Windows Azure Websites

Tags: azure, ssl, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service, client-certificates

I am developing a windows service application that will run on customer PC/servers and access a Web API endpoint hosted in an Azure Website. It needs to authenticate the user, and I would prefer not storing credentials on the customer's machine.  So, I've landed on client certificates to authenticate the users.  I have this working against a local, non-Azure Website IIS instance with self-signed certificates.  However, I'm unable to get it working in an Azure Website.

As far as I can tell, there are two issues that I'm not finding much documentation on:

- How do I install my own CA certificate in the Trusted Root of the Website instance(s)?  Or will this only work with CA certificates that are already trusted?
- How do I enable "Accept Client Certificates" for this application?  In IIS you do this under "SSL Settings".  Documentation indicates that modifying the system.webServer/security/access node of app.config will accomplish this, but obviously you can't do that in Websites.  Documentation for websites suggests this node is unlocked for use in web.config, however adding that node results in an error "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.", even if custom errors is off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Azure web sites vs web roles client authentication options are rather limited. Websites don't let you run programs with elevated permissions, which is required for making IIS changes and storing certificates into the trusted root.

There's a way to configure you website to always (you don't get the benefit of making it optional as with IIS 'Accept' configuration) request client certificate. This feature is currently only available through Azure management REST API, you can't access it through the portal UI. You can find more information [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-configure-tls-mutual-auth/). 
Essentially you turn on clientCertEnabled website setting to true. The mechanics of this option are different from traditional client authentication where server needs to have a CA certificate with which the client cert is signed in its trusted root. The server doesn't run any validation on the client certificate, the application needs to run the cert check itself, which comes in a request header "X-ARR-ClientCert". GetClientCertificate() extension method on HttpRequestMessage will parse it automatically.

Alternatively, you can host your Web API as a web role. That gives access to running startup tasks with elevated permissions that allows access to trusted root and making IIS configurations, more details/examples [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/applisec/2013/04/07/client-certificates-in-windows-azure/). You can either copy the CA certificate to the app folder or upload to the user store via Azure portal so that it is available for copying over to the trusted root in a startup task. IIS changes can be made via “Microsoft.Web.Administration” library available as NuGet package through ServerManager class.

Comment: Setting clientCertEnabled does not result in the server sending "certificateRequested" and demanding client certs.

Answer (score 1):

For question 2, here's a blog post on how to install client certificates on Azure Websites: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/27/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/

For question 1, you can't install your own CA certs as trusted root certificates, but if you have certs from a CA that's already trusted then you can use them without any issues.

Comment: I ran across this in my research and tried doing what they describe.  My understanding is that this is how one would store a certificate for use from code inside a website.  It does not allow the website to accept client certificates.